# generic controller with arguments in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 views which use the same logic but with 3 different services for their respective json. So I end up with 3 controllers with the same code, what change is the service injected and some variables names:

**fooController.js**

```
var jsonFoo = {};
function displayFoo(data) {
    jsonFoo = data.foo;
    $scope.foo = jsonFoo;
}
$scope.switch = function (n) {
    jsonFoo[n] = !jsonFoo[n];
}
...
function getData(currentpage) {
    fooService
    .getFoo(currentpage)
    .then(displayFoo);
}
...
```

**barController.js**

```
var jsonBar = {};
function displayBar(data) {
    jsonBar = data.bar;
    $scope.bar = jsonBar;
}
$scope.switch = function (n) {
    jsonBar[n] = !jsonBar[n];
}
...
function getData(currentpage) {
    barService
    .getBar(currentpage)
    .then(displayBar);
}
...
```

**bazController.js**

```
var jsonBaz = {};
function displayBaz(data) {
    jsonBaz = data.baz;
    $scope.baz = jsonBaz;
}
$scope.switch = function (n) {
    jsonBaz[n] = !jsonBaz[n];
}
...
function getData(currentpage) {
    bazService
    .getBaz(currentpage)
    .then(displayBaz);
}
...
```

If services are singleton, and controllers isolate scope, how can I refactor and make all this generic ?

Thanx.

Comment: I would have one service, and if the `foo`, `bar` and `baz` logic is identical then have a property in the server that determines whether you're doing `foo`, `bar` or `baz` work.

Comment: Yes I've just refactored my 3 services into one before reading your answser... But I'm still stuck with my 3 controllers, and I don't want to have anything else that my json webservices on the server. As an SPA, I need to do logic on the frontend.

Comment: just an idea, but if you want to avoid as much code repetition as possible then you could maybe develop a base controller and inherit from that for your 3 ones so the only thing that changes in the derived controllers is some way to tell the service to do foo bar or baz work.

Comment: Yes I considered the refactoring into one base controller and use of inheritance, but my 3 controllers are identical, so I would have nothing in the base controller... or everything... I need to have one controller but I can't figure out how to pass variables names and instantiate a controller constructor with arguments like in OOP...

Comment: Off-topic as the question is on refactoring